# passing an object by const& and by & to the same function

Tags: c++, const-correctness

I have an image function declared as

```
thresholding( const Image &imgSrc, Image &imgDest );
```

What happens if I do this;

```
Image img;
tresholding( img, img );
```

Is this well-defined? Because in this case `img` is changed.

P.S: `threshold` reads `imgSrc` and if `imgSrc[i] < lowerThr -> imgDest[i] = 255 else imgDest[i] = 0

And to be more precise:

```
__m128i _mm_src = _mm_load_si128 ( any_value );
__m128i _mm_src = _mm_load_si128 ( (__m128i*) &imgSrc[0] );
__m128i _mm_dest = _mm_load_si128 ( (__m128i*) &imgDest[0] );


_mm_dest = mm_cmpgt_epi16 (a, thr);
```

Comment: _"Is this well-defined?"_ What should be undefined about it?

Comment: I suppose you want to call the function `treshold` in your 2nd code block instead of `thresholding` and `Image img()` is a function declaration.

Comment: @JN11 absoluetly right, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having multiple references with possibly differing type to one object (just as having multiple pointers to the same object) is not problematic. The behavior of the function may be fine too: An expression like

```
imgDest[i] = (imgSrc[i] < lowerThr) * 255;
```

is well-defined for `imgSrc` and `imgDest` referring to the same object. No problems with sequencing o.s. occur. You should check the documentation or the source for `threshold` though, too be sure - It may be implemented in a way that requires `imgSrc` to be constant throughout execution. You shouldn't make assumptions without knowledge of the implementation.

Comment: Does the compiler, then only checks if the imgSrc object is changed via imgSrc?

Comment: @user1235183 What do you mean? The compiler won't issue a diagnostic if the behavior of the function is nonsensical or undefined. Check the documentation.

Answer (score 4):

Whether this is well-defined depends on the specification of the function. The language allows multiple references to the same object, even if some are `const`-qualified and others aren't, but many functions do not. Any modifications made through `imgDest` will *immediately* be visible through `imgSrc`, and many functions with parameters similar to yours assume that after modifications to `imgDest`, the original image is still available in `imgSrc`. If your function makes such an assumption, then it's easy to say that the language allows such a call, but that's like saying the language allows `printf(NULL);`: sure, technically it does, but if you also consider the specification of the function, that's still undefined.